# Are all files outside of /home/userabc owned by root?

Tags: files, arch-linux, directory-structure, chown

I'm writing a tar implementation for a package manager, and I wonder if I can skip the permission setting of the user in the tar headers and keep what is there by default, the user who wrote the files, in my case root.

Would this present a problem? The package manager is designed to not write anything inside /home.

Comment: Good luck with that as most systems use a few dozens of user accounts and at least a few different groups to manage the basic installation.  Since it's your package manager, you're the boss.  Just don't try to use it on someone else's system if you don't want any trouble.

Comment: I would also like to point out that the permissions are also normally intelligently applied with security in mind, so don't forget to reproduce the proven logic that's been in place for decennials.

Comment: I couldn't resist in making a final comment.  Don't you think that the hundreds of package managers that already exist do a better job than a custom stripped down version of tar?

Comment: I did not say im writing tar as an package manager. Thanks for your salty input.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude but after reading this comment and rereading your question, you did.

Comment: Why are you writing a tar implementation? What's wrong with the existing implementations?

Comment: Youngster programming exercise and there is none except Apache Commons for Java, which i don't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most* but not *all* files that are part of the system are owned by the root user. It's rare for system files not to be owned by root, because a user that owns system files can modify them and this is usually not desirable. It's a lot more common to have files that are owned by a *group* other than root, and that have mode 660 or 664 or 640.

It's possible to design a Unix system where all system files (outside of `/dev`, `/home`, and the parts of `/var` containing user data such as mailboxes and crontabs) are owned by root. I don't know whether this is the case for Arch Linux. But not allowing files to be owned by a different group would significantly restrict the security protections of the system, it wouldn't be viable. So you'll need to remember group ownership anyway. Why not remember user ownership as well?

Comment: Great answer! I was avoiding it because Java does not like playing with *nix and its a mess to set users and groups via pure Java. What I will need to do is write a simple JNI bridge between Java and the GNU C Library.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  All files outside of home directories are not owned by root.

There is a rich and complex set of users and groups, and permissions, on files outside of user home directories for a number of reasons, some historical, and some security related.

However, tar implementations have two usual modes, they either,

1. restore files and directories and set the owner to whoever ran the tar
2. restore files and directories with permissions set based on those which were stored inside the tar file

The latter is usually only possible if you are root already.